# Why does my SASS style only apply partially?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, css-loader, storybook, sass-loader

I'm creating a react component library. Styling needs to be isolated, apart from some global variables. My styling is not applying everywhere, only on some pages. Why is this and how can I fix it?

My webpack.config.js:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = async ({ config, mode }) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
            'style-loader',
            {
                loader: 'css-loader',
                options: {
                    modules: {
                        mode: 'local',
                        localIdentName:
                            '[name]-[local]-[hash:base64:3]',
                    },
                    import: true,
                    importLoaders: true,
                }
            },
            {
                loader: 'sass-loader',
            },
            {
                loader: 'sass-resources-loader',
                options: {
                    resources: [
                        path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/styles/variables/_variables.scss'),
                        path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/styles/variables/_header.scss'),
                        path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/styles/variables/_footer.scss')
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
    });
    return config;
};
```

For example: I have a module "Checkbox". The story for the module is below. The first story is styled, the second story is not.

```
stories.add('Empty', () => (
    <Checkbox />
));

stories.add('With Label', () => (
    <Checkbox  classes={propsClasses} field={'Field'} label={'Label'} />
));
```

EDIT:
With the webpack.config.js below, all the styles load. But then ALL the styles load on EVERY page. Which makes for duplicate style and no longer an isolated component.

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = async ({ config, mode }) => {

    config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
            'style-loader',
            {
                loader: 'css-loader',
                options: {
                    modules: {
                        mode: 'local',
                        localIdentName: '[local]',
                    },
                    import: true,
                    importLoaders: true,
                }
            },
            {
                loader: 'sass-loader',
            },
            {
                loader: 'sass-resources-loader',
                options: {
                    resources: [
                        path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/styles/variables/_variables.scss'),
                        path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/styles/variables/_header.scss'),
                        path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/styles/variables/_footer.scss')
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
    });
    return config;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Webpack bundles CSS files when they are `require`d, the same way it bundles JS files when they are `require`d. When using `sass-loader`, `css-loader`, and `style-loader`, the `require` will pass the Sass source code through those loaders and the result is JS code that will insert the transpiled CSS into a `<style>` element on the page at runtime. That JS code is what gets added to the bundle webpack creates.

I'm not familiar with `sass-resources-loader`, but per its README, `This loader will @import your SASS resources into every required SASS module` -- this is likely why you're seeing all of your styles imported for each module...?

To isolate your styles on a per-component basis, you probably want a `.scss` file for each component that contains styles for that component, and to `require()` that `.scss` file in its JS module. Because webpack processes each Sass file independently, as it's `require`d, each component's Sass file will need to import any variables/mixins it needs. (It sounds like `sass-resources-loader` is trying to handle that for you, but not giving the desired results?)

How are you loading your Sass files currently?